# Should we get rid of the [data-request] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over half the questions have the [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) tag, and the tag also applies to a lot of [questions that don't have the tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bdata-request%5D+is%3Aquestion). It seems to me that this tag doesn't add much in terms of filtering.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tag was created because the forum has changed over time. At some times there are lots of data requests and at others the questions were focused on standards, the nature of this Stack Exchange, or open data platforms. I think the tag provides context for the question and helps those who are interested in answering data hunt questions.